# Static IP's and moving networks, assigning through web interface or windows settings

Tags: windows, networking, router, ip, ip-address

If I were to assign a static IP to a laptop on one network through the windows interface to 192.168.1.10 (on Ethernet - for example), and then take this laptop home, will the IP address stay on this 192.168.1.10 when I get home?

Also, when assigning a static IP is it essential to do this both on the router and through the windows adapter settings or is only one required?

Cheers for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  A static IP assignment will remain until you change it or tell it to no longer be static.

> Also, when assigning a static IP is it essential to do this both on the router and through the windows adapter settings or is only one required?

If you mean change your router's IP, no, you don't want to do that.  Your router needs a fixed IP that is unique from every other device on your network - and it shouldn't change very often.

A system can get an IP automatically through a protocol called DHCP (this is what's happening when you use the "Obtain an IP address automatically" setting) - and most home routers run DHCP.  Many routers support something called "reservations" where the router's DHCP can be set to always give out a specific IP whenever a system with a specific MAC address asks for one.  This is setup and done on the router, and if you do this, you want to leave the system set to automatically get an address.

Comment: It should be added that this is something of mistaken design, as it leads to annoyances like having to manually edit network configurations every time you go home or to work. The solution mentioned here (DHCP reservations) avoids a lot of headaches.

Comment: Awesome, thanks @LawrenceC. This helps alot. What I meant by assigning the static IP on my router was the "static lease" option, whereby you assign a specific MAC address an IP. So if I did this would I need to also choose my own static IP through the adapter settings on the associated machine too? But I guess this is what you meant by reservations so thankyou